# Is there any way to save all graphs generated using the script to a single file (image preferably)

Tags: python, graph

The scripts I use generate a lot of graphs. I was wondering if there was a way to save them or specified ones into a single file as image or pdf for quicklooks.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean matplotlib graphs, or node-edge graphs from something like NetworkX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using matplotlib, it would be easiest to use the subplots feature. This will make all of your graphs part of a single object, which can be saved as an image like you want. I would redirect you to the matplotlib website for a ton of good example on the subject. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Then, do

```
fig.savefig('mysweetsubplots.png')
```

and you are done.